# The element h1 must not appear as a descendant of the address element

Tags: html, seo, semantic-web, semantic-markup, microdata

I'm developing a personal website and the first section must contain the author details (like organization he works for and email). I'm trying to setup the content for the search engine crawlers.

I'm using HTML 5 and microdata. Below is the code:

```
<header>
  <address itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <h1 lang="pt" itemprop="name">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/200/" lang="pt" alt="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet">
    <p itemprop="jobTitle">Professor of ...</p>
    <div itemprop="worksFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
      <span itemprop="department" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span lang="pt" itemprop="name">Departamento de ...</span></span><br>
      <span itemprop="name" lang="pt">Faculdade de Engenharia ...</span><br>
      <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Rua Dr. Roberto ...</span>, <span itemprop="postalCode">4200-465</span> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Porto, Portugal</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Email: <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a></p>
  </address>
</header>
```

Using the W3C validator, I get the error:

```
Line 11, Column 38: The element h1 must not appear as a descendant of the address element.

<h1 lang="pt" itemprop="name">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
```

I understand the error. I'm using a `h1` because the author's name is also the name of the website.

**My question is how would you solve this?**

Comment: ....move it above the <address>?

Comment: @Diodeus that would break the semantic meaning.

Comment: You can use an H1 for the page and an H2 for the address.

Comment: No heading is valid inside an `address`.

Comment: I've done some work with the schema.org stuff. It doesn't always fit.

Comment: @Diodeus it doesn't have anything to do with the schema.org stuff;  it's the HTML specification that says what elements can appear in others.

Comment: Note that HTML5 (which is still in flux) says about [the address element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/sections.html#the-address-element) that "The address element represents the contact information for its nearest article or body element ancestor. If that is the body element, then the contact information applies to the document as a whole."  It doesn't really make sense for a title to appear in such an element.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The title appears in the address, because it's equals to the author. What about switching the `h1` by a `meta` tag so that we would still have the author's name with semantic meaning? (And of course putting the heading before the `address`.)

Comment: Lots of things appear in multiple places, but it doesn't mean that they're the same thing.  I don't send correspondence to the title of a document, I send it to the correspondence address.  They're different things, even if they happen to share some text.  If someone else becomes the maintainer of the document, then their name should be listed in the address, even though the title of the document would remain the same.  The title and contact person are different things, semantically.  If you don't want to _show_ one of those things, that's an issue for CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Even if the title is the same as the author's name, they correspond to different things. Moved up the heading and added a `meta` tag with the person's name in the `address`.

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 lang="pt">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
    <address itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      <meta lang="pt" itemprop="name" content="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet">
      <img itemprop="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/200/" lang="pt" alt="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet">
      <p itemprop="jobTitle">Professor of ...</p>
      <div itemprop="worksFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <span itemprop="department" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span lang="pt" itemprop="name">Departamento de ...</span></span><br>
        <span itemprop="name" lang="pt">Faculdade de Engenharia ...</span><br>
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
          <span itemprop="streetAddress">Rua Dr. Roberto ...</span>, <span itemprop="postalCode">4200-465</span> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Porto, Portugal</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Email: <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a></p>
    </address>
  </header>
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm..

Renato Rodrigues: "I understand the error. I'm using a h1 because the author's name is also the name of the website."

if the author's name is also the name of the website, then the author's address is the address of the document, the address of your html page, right ?

that header is the header of your body or the header of a section within body ?
if it's the header of a section then you need to get it out of there and place it straight on body:
example: http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_address_tag.php

Comment: It's the header of the body.

Comment: "The address element allows you to mark up contact information for the whole web page if address nested inside `footer` and `footer` nested inside `body`" Will this apply if the parent container is a `header` instead of a `footer`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if it's the header of the body then it's ok: address inside header, header straight on body